# Creating notes in Visual Studio 2015+

Tags: visual-studio, comments, tooling

How would one create various types of notes in Visual Studio? The goal is to not abuse comments or bookmark's names to achieve that.

An ideal solution would look like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tkrkt.linenote

It creates a text file linked to the portion of code of your choice but sadly it's only available for VS Code and not Visual Studio.

I ideally need being able to version these notes as if they were part of the code directly (but they must not).

**Related question:** [How can I add a note to a Visual Studio bookmark or line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14981680/1524913)

As the aforementioned question only covers version of Visual Studio prior to 2015 or offer a solution OP has turned down (using Bookmark's name), here I am.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask for, but you can try my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension.

It allows you create notes, but they are associated with a task, not a code block. And portions of code also can be associated with the same task.